# Why my .Net cannot find dotnet-c:\Users\...?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

After adding the C# Dev Kit extension to VS Code, every time I open any solution it displays a message:

Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
Possible reasons for this include:

- You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
- You intended to execute a .NET program, but dotnet-c:\Users\Mateusz does not exist.
- You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.

I have all the necessary SDKs installed, everything works from the terminal. The problem only occurs when the C# Dev Kit extension is loaded.

In Solution Explorer, after expanding the project, it displays the message: A compatible .NET SDK was not found.

A similar problem occurs when launching VS 2022.

I repeatedly reinstalled all the components needed to work, checked the environment variables